# Mixing condensed and evaporated milk for fudge?

Tags: evaporated-milk

Before anybody says this is a duplicate, I'm not asking about the difference between the two milks; I already know that. What I'm looking for is a way to lessen the sugar content of sweetened condensed milk without changing the texture of the final product too much.

Nestle makes a 50% less sugar version of sweetened condensed milk, but that isn't available within 50 miles of my home, so I'm trying to find a different solution

If I use half sweetened condensed milk and half evaporated milk, will I end up with lower-sugar sweetened condensed milk or will I end up with a watery, useless product that can't become fudge?

Answer (score 2):

This is the label information from the reduced sugar sweetened condensed milk made by [Nestlé](http://www.elmejornido.com/en/la-lechera/products/sweetened-condensed-milk-with-50-less-sugar):

[image]

That suggests to me that there is more to creating a lower sugar sweetened condensed milk than simply reducing the sugar. I have made sweetened condensed milk from evaporated milk (goat's milk actually), and I found the experience a bit more advanced than simply slowly stirring simmering milk, and the sugar seemed very crucial to the operation. [Cajeta with powdered goat's milk? Or evaporated? (Experiment Results)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/cajeta-with-powdered-goats-milk-or-evaporated-experiment-results)

For comparison sake I looked at the ingredient list for regular Nestlé sweetened condensed milk (La Lechera). The ingredients of that product are milk and sugar.

I won't go so far as to say that it can't be done as you hope, nor will I say that the fudge wouldn't be tasty, but I have serious doubts.

Answer (score -1):

If you have normal milk and some time. Then you can cook the milk for a long duration of time, constantly stirring so that it doesn't burn. Keep the sweetness lower as compared to your need as the reduction in volume will normalize that. It will really take a long time but the taste will remain awesome.

Comment: Do you think that'll work for fudge, though? I can easily see all the sugar being an important part of the structure/texture of the fudge. Seems like it might take an incredibly long time (and a lot of stirring) to get it as thick as condensed milk without burning it, too.

Comment: It will for sure work for fudge. First heat the milk and let it condensed for a moment and at the end, when you feel that the thickness is ok, then add sugar as sugar melts right away and lead to burn the milk.

Comment: I'm still not at all convinced. The thickness added by the sugar is important to the texture of the fudge. I'm sure it's possible to reach the same thickness by reducing milk an awful lot, but that leads to a few issues. You'll have to use tons and tons of milk to start with (since there's not much in it to thicken it). The thickness will be provided partially by sugar (so there's not as much nutritional gain as you'd think) and partially by protein (so it won't lead to the same texture). Unless you've actually tried this, I don't think you can confidently say it'll work.