# How can I replace sweetened condensed milk in key lime pie with goat's milk?

Tags: milk, pie, goat

I want to make a Key Lime pie using only goat's milk(cow's milk allergy issues). The filing is usually, if not always, made with condensed milk. No one sells sweetened condensed goat milk - not even Meyenberg. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/cajeta-with-powdered-goats-milk-or-evaporated-experiment-results

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sweetened condensed milk recipe using evaporated goat milk.

- 1 - 12 oz can evaporated goat milk; 1-1/2 cup sugar.
- Combine and simmer at least 30 min stirring often.

Maybe not as thick as "regular" condensed milk but when 4 egg yolks and 1/2 cup of lime juice are added it sets up just fine when baked in a graham cracker pie shell. A perfectly acceptable non-cow's milk Key Lime pie filling.

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet would be to either make your own sweetened condensed milk using the goat milk or to use a different non-dairy substitute - apparently they sell sweetened condensed non-dairy milks, specifically coconut.

Apparently many of the recipes for homemade sweetened condensed milk use powdered milk, which might be troublesome but I did find [this one](https://www.kitchenstewardship.com/recipes/healthy-homemade-sweetened-condensed-milk/) or [this one](https://glutenfreeonashoestring.com/homemade-sweetened-condensed-milk/) that use whole milk. I don't think there's any reason it shouldn't work with goat milk instead of cow's.

Alternately, you can find a recipe that doesn't use sweetened condensed milk at all... a vegan one or a non-dairy one should do the trick. I'm sure there's tons of options out there.

Comment: I made an amazing key lime pie with tofu once. I wish I still had the recipe, I liked it far better than the dairy version!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Last night I made the filling using a can of evaporated goat milk and sugar. Simmered at least 45 min. Then added the lime juice, lime zest and egg yolks. Baked in a Keebler non-diary graham cracker pie crust, 350º, 30 min then chilled.Very firm texture and tasty. Making whipped cream with evap goat milk was a disaster. Very runny. Next time either meringue topping or non-dairy whipped cream product.

Comment: @TonyCassens You're more than welcome to answer your own question with that information. I had no idea that condensed goat milk was even an option!