# How much evaporated milk do I use for a half a cup of milk

Tags: fudge

I'm trying to make peanut butter fudge and it's calling for a half a cup of milk I don't have milk I'd like to know if I can substitute evaporated milk

Comment: Check out the question that was asked before -- certainly looks like you can! (Just [dilute it first](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/62577/17272)!)

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate of a question regarding *condensed* milk,  which it isn't. In the US condensed milk is *always* sweetened. After searching 100s of results on Amazon, I have come to believe that *any* canned milk labeled as "condensed" in English is, in fact, "sweetened condensed milk". Some labels omit the word "sweetened" in the title, but further reading shows that these products are the same syrupy milk product that is common in North, Central, and South America.

Comment: So now I am closing this question as a duplicate of a question that has been asked before regarding *evaporated* milk.

Answer (score 1):

In order to substitute **evaporated milk** for regular milk, you need to reconstitute the milk according to package instructions. Usually, that's a 1 to 1 ratio. So you would use 1/4 cup each of evaporated milk and water. (double check the label, other concentrations may exist)

See: [Can evaporated milk be converted to "regular" milk?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35684/can-evaporated-milk-be-converted-to-regular-milk)