# Can I make drinking milk with evaporated milk?

Tags: mixing

Can I mix evaporated milk with water to make milk to drink? I am finding it hard to get to the store to get milk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can evaporated milk be converted to "regular" milk?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35684/can-evaporated-milk-be-converted-to-regular-milk) (You definitely can, by the way! That other question will tell you how.)

Answer (score 4):

You can make something approximately 'milk-like' though it will taste more like that revolting UHT stuff they put in hotel rooms with the tea & coffee.
It will never go back to being 'fresh milk'.

Try it & see.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my recipe:

1. Take one cup of evaporated milk
2. Add one cup water
3. Mix thoroughly
4. Pour down the drain

Seriously, evaporated milk will never taste like fresh milk, but there's a dietary need you can use it but will have to get used to the taste. A 1:1 ratio is probably a good starting place. If you have any cream or half-and-half you can add in that might help.

You might try almond milk instead which is easy to make at home and can have a rich, creamy flavor (in my opinion homemade almond milk is a million times better than any store-bought. Not 900K times; one million). The best way to make this is in a blender like a Vitamix. All you need is a cup or so of almonds (presoak overnight) a pinch of salt, and 3-4 cups of water. Blend for a few minutes at high speed. I sometimes add an emulsifier to this and blend an additional minute. Heating also helps emulsify (a Vitamix will heat by itself if in for long enough). The hard part is squeezing through a nut bag. Also messy. Another method is using a Nutramilk which is faster and easier and you don't have to soak the almonds (and shouldn't) and don't have to use a nut bag. There's also much less waste of the nuts.

If you don't have a Vitamix or Nutramilk you can use any kind of high-speed blender or food processor and will probably get decent results.

Hope this helps.